# Can autoencoders learn sound transformations?

Tags: autoencoders, generative-models

I've been working on the generation of music. Particularly, given a *target* sound I would like this sound to be modified depending on an *input* signal. Say, I play the piano and I want to generate a drum sequence based on the targeted one. Both sounds are in a time-frequency representation (STFT).

I'm reading [here](http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/tutorials/algorithms/autoencoders.html) that during the training the target is set equal to the input. What if I set the target equal to something else, *i.e.* a sound *other* than the input?

A second hypothesis would be to train an autoencoder only on a family of targets, *e.g.* drum sounds, and to encode the input sound in a way such that it can be used for conditioning in a generative model - [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6527-conditional-image-generation-with-pixelcnn-decoders.pdf) should do something similar. But I see this as an *expensive* choice, especially in a real-time context.

Comment: Have you seen this paper? WaveNet auto-encoder applied as synthesizer for musical notes, also new instrument dataset: https://t.co/kGz1XGi666 Can interpolate timbre! https://t.co/l4AXK2aEAw . One problem with autoencoders trained on stft is the synthesis. Wavenet will generate the audio itself.

Comment: @Anoosh that seems pretty cool, thanks! I think however WaveNet is still not capable of real-time generation.

Comment: yea ... I guess not yet

Comment: if you are still interested, Google improved the wavenet to be online capable. Check out their new post: https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-launches-google-assistant/